# Can you convert from a split-wire duplex receptacle?

Tags: kitchens

I’m not sure of the correct vernacular but hopefully what I’m trying to describe makes sense.

I have a duplex receptacle that has red, black and white all wired (fwiw: the box has one red, one black, one white) This is controlled at the panel by 2 15A circuits that are handle-tied.  I think this is called a split-wired duplex receptacle.

There is one other receptacle on the wall that is also controlled by this same handle-tied breaker pack.

What I would like to do is switch out one receptacle for a conventional receptacle (because it’s only conventional receptacles that I can find that have built-in USB ports that I need to add to this area).

How can I convert the one receptacle to a conventional one, while preserving the split duplex functionality of the second?

Is it as easy as capping off the red and connecting the black and white to the new receptacle?

Comment: It sounds like that is what to do.  I am assuming this outlet is the last one on the circuit with just one cable, one black, one red, and one white.  The other outlet should have two cables of each one.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this. I made the assumption that the other box would have exactly the same wiring.  I just checked and you’re right, it has two feeds into it, each with a black, red and a white.  So I am indeed looking to swap out the last receptacle in the line.

Comment: Just remember if replacing the outlet in the future, the tab on the hot side need to be removed if using the red(or black) again.  Check the old outlet and will find the small piece of metal between the two hot screws missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Multi-Wire Branch Circuit or MWBC.

As noted in comments, this is the last duplex receptacle in the series. Because of that, you can cape one wire (e.g., red) and connect the other two wires to a new duplex receptacle, which can have USB or other special features. But a few things to consider:

##### Kitchen == GFCI

Most receptacles in a kitchen require GFCI protection. There are some exceptions but for ordinary countertop convenience receptacles (which this sounds like) GFCI is almost always required. That can be one of three places:

- Breaker

This is expensive but simple, provided your panel has such breakers available. Which means (a) that your panel is one of several relatively common major brands (likely) and (b) that the handle-tied pair of breakers is a pair of regular full-size breakers. Half-size (a.k.a., tandem or double-stuff) breakers generally are not available with GFCI.

- GFCI all by itself

Not an option for an MWBC, at least not unless it is split into two separate branches, one for each hot wire/breaker.

- GFCI at the receptacle

Also not an option for an MWBC, at least not unless it is split into two separate branches, one for each hot wire/breaker. For the last in the series (as described in this question) that is an option, and there are [receptacles with GFCI and USB such as this Leviton from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-15-Amp-Smartlock-Pro-Self-Test-GFCI-Combination-24-Watt-4-8-Amp-Type-A-USB-In-Wall-Charger-Duplex-Outlet-White-R02-GUSB1-0BW/317233129):

[image: GFCI USB]

However, adding GFCI at the last receptacle only helps for that receptacle, not any earlier ones in the chain.

That being said, if GFCI was not required *at the time the receptacles where originally installed* then you generally don't need to add it now. But it is good *life safety* protection and therefore a really good idea.

##### MWBC Correctly Wired?

Depending on a bunch of things, it is possible to have what appears to be an MWBC that is actually not wired correctly. That can be dangerous because it can lead to an overloaded neutral wire. Easy to tell from a picture of the panel. But also easy to tell by checking voltage between the wires. If black->white and red->white are ~ 120V and black->red is ~ 240V then everything is good. But if black->red is ~ 0V then you have a serious problem that needs fixing, which is far more important than getting USB. (It won't prevent adding USB, just it needs to get it resolved *first*.)